# Convenient way to find a lambda mentioned in log

Tags: android, logging

Lambda expressions are easy to write, easy to read but hard to find when we talk about logs.

I got next stack trace in the Fabric Crashlytics (and I could see such errors in Android Monitor). The question is if there is some convenient way to find this "`Lambda #7`" in the class?

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: The mapper function returned a null value.
    at io.reactivex.internal.functions.a.a(ObjectHelper.java:39)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ay$a.onNext(ObservableMap.java:59)
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

---> at com.myapp.MyClass$$Lambda$7.accept(Unknown Source)
       at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onError(LambdaObserver.java:77)
       at io.reactivex.internal.observers.BasicFuseableObserver.onError(BasicFuseableObserver.java:100)
       at io.reactivex.internal.observers.BasicFuseableObserver.fail(BasicFuseableObserver.java:110)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableMap$MapObserver.onNext(ObservableMap.java:61)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate$CreateEmitter.onNext(ObservableCreate.java:67)
       at io.objectbox.rx.RxQuery$4$1.onData(RxQuery.java:95)
       at io.objectbox.rx.RxQuery$4$1.onData(RxQuery.java:91)
       at io.objectbox.query.QueryPublisher$2.run(QueryPublisher.java:68)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using the Android Studio's `Navigate -> File Structure` view (MacOs: `Cmd+F12`, Windows: `Ctrl+F12`). You should check `Lambdas` checkbox there and then you will see the lamdas with theis numbers:

[image]

Comment: in kotlin files labdas check box wont show . do you have any solution for this . thanks